# How to send data to Servlet from Android by doPost

Tags: java, android, servlets

I send data to servlet from HTML, it will work successfully.

But from Android, it will pass to next **Intent**. Servlet will show **"NULL"**, had no data.

Could anyone please tell me where I am wrong? Thank you!

**Servlet Code:**

```
public class SocialServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override 
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
                        throws IOException,ServletException{
            this.doPost(request,response);
    }
    @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
                String json_array = request.getParameter("array");
                out.println(json_array);
    }
}
```

**Android Code:**

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.103:8080/social/social.do");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("array", "teststring")); 
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params)); 
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: define 'it will fail'

Comment: It only show "null", didn't had any string data

Comment: what kind of debugging have you done so far?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised you haven't gotten your question answered. I had a similar problem. Due to time constraints, a way around that problem was to append what you need to the end of the url. I was using Jax-RS so I was using rest. But something similar could be accomplished in your case. Though why those params are not appearing as parameters at the server side is strange. Have you figured it out?

Comment: Dear @Andy 
I use method=get via HTML submit, Servlet link:<http://192.168.0.105:8080/social/social.do?array=test >, use method=post via HTML submit, Servlet link:<http://192.168.0.105:8080/social/social.do >. These two of methods via HTML will pass show string on Servlet.

Comment: But I use HttpPost on Android, and setting open  <http://192.168.0.105:8080/social/social.do> on Android Browser after send string. Servlet web will show NULL. I didn't know you mean is method by GET??